# My <S-Left> and <S-Right> key mapping doesn't work in macvim

Tags: vim, macvim

I'm using [spf13-vim](https://github.com/spf13/spf13-vim) and want to map `Shift+Left` to `gt` and `Shift+Right` to `gT`, the following is what I added to my `.vimrc.local`:

```
map <S-Right> gT
map <S-Left> gt
```

but it does not work. And when I view `:verbose map <S-Right>` I got a different result`gtt>`:

[:verbose map result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMOam.png)

Comment: Try to do the following: enter insert mode, press Ctrl + V, and then press Shift + Left. What does it print?

Comment: By the way, which Vim version are you using?

Comment: @thalesmello, I found the reason, because I open vim inside Tmux, the Shift + Left key binding is captured by Tmux.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the root cause, it's because I open vim inside tmux, the `Shift + Left` key binding is captured by Tmux.

Leave the answer here, hope it can help others :-)